# PowerPoint VBA: How to save each slide individually as new presentations?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am working on a huge Powerpoint file which seems to be a file too big. In order to figure out which slides cause the big size of the file and to be able to make it smaller, I was trying to save each slide as an individual file.

Older versions of Powerpoint did the trick using the Publish function which isn't available any more. So I tried to create this myself using a VBA macro, even though I'm fairly new to VBA. Please see the code below:

```vb
Sub slidesizes()

    Dim L As Long
    Dim originPres As Presentation
    Dim tempPres As Presentation

    Set originPres = ActivePresentation
    originPres.SaveCopyAs (Environ("TEMP") & "\temppres.pptx")

    On Error Resume Next
    MkDir (Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\slides\")
    Set tempPres = Presentations.Open(FileName:=Environ("TEMP") & "\temppres.pptx", WithWindow:=False)
    For L = originPres.Slides.Count To 1 Step -1
        originPres.Slides(L).Copy
        tempPres.Slides.Paste
        Call tempPres.SaveAs(FileName:=Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\slides\slide" & L & ".pptx", EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False)
        tempPres.Slides(1).Delete
    Next
    tempPres.Close
End Sub
```

When using this macro, powerpoint saves files for all slides, but they all contain more than just one slide. Where is the mistake in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tempPres contains more than one slide... Try to delete all but one slide before you go into your For L Loop.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see this. The mistake was to use a copy of the origin file as the tempPres. I put in `Presentations.Add.SaveAs (Environ("TEMP") & "\temppres.pptx")` instead of `originPres.SaveCopyAs (Environ("TEMP") & "\temppres.pptx")` and now it seems to work just fine.

Comment: You are welcome! In my opinion it is better to use a copy and delete the unused slides. Otherwise you can get problems if your presentation-master is different to the master of your standard-presentation.